# How can I transform my data with numbers to a dictionary containing lists of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2112.0,545.0,2136.0,554.0
```

What I want to do is read a `.txt` file full of hundreds of values like the ones shared above, to create a dictionary who's key is the value of the first 2 numbers in it; my expected output:

```
mydict = {
    '10-0': [[2089,545,2100,545,2100,546,2089,546], 
             [2112,545,2136,545,2136,554,2112,554]],
}
```

to explain how we went from 4 numbers to 8 numbers let's see them as `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` at first, and in the output they are combined as `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `x1`, `y2`

In the actual data I have hundreds of values so I will have different keys if the starting 2 elements are different. Let's say if the line in the .txt file starts with `values/test/10/blueprint-1.png` then the key is `'10-1'`.

What I have tried:

```
import re

import itertools

file_data = [re.findall('\d+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('ground_truth')]
print(file_data)
final_data = [['{}-{}'.format(a, b), list(map(float, c))] for a, b, *c in file_data]
new_data = {a: list(map(lambda x: x[-1], b)) for a, b in
            itertools.groupby(sorted(final_data, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

but instead I get

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)
```

and I can't seem to fix my issue from a simple file with these 2 lines in it to the answer expected in `mydict`.

Note that taking this line for example `values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0` we will find these numbers `[10, 0, 2089, 0, 545, 0, 2100, 0, 546, 0]` and the `0`s in the elements 3, 5, 7 and 9 are irrelevant considering these numbers are in a list. These can be seen by printing `file_data`, as I did in the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use a more sophisticated regular expression to ignore the decimal `.0` values:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\d+', i)
```

This uses a negative look-behind, to ignore any digits that are preceded by a `.`. This will ignore `.0`, but if there's a `.01`, then those extra digits beyond the `.0` (or `.<digit>`) will still be picked up. For your input that should suffice.

I'd use a regular loop here to make the code more readable, and to keep the code O(N) instead of O(NlogN) (the sorting is not needed):

```
new_data = {}
with open('ground_truth') as f:
    for line in f:
        k1, k2, x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\d+', line))
        key = '{}-{}'.format(k1, k2)
        new_data.setdefault(key, []).append([x1, y1, x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2])
```

I hardcoded your `x, y` combinations here, as you seem to have a very specific desired order.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> file_data = '''\
... values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0
... values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2112.0,545.0,2136.0,554.0
... '''
>>> new_data = {}
>>> for line in file_data.splitlines(True):
...     k1, k2, x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\d+', line))
...     key = '{}-{}'.format(k1, k2)
...     new_data.setdefault(key, []).append([x1, y1, x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2])
...
>>> new_data
{'10-0': [[2089, 545, 2100, 545, 2100, 546, 2089, 546], [2112, 545, 2136, 545, 2136, 554, 2112, 554]]}
```

A good alternative is to just treat your input file as the CSV format that it is! Using the `csv` module is a good way to split out the columns, after which you only need to deal with the digits in the first filename column:

```
import csv, re

new_data = {}
with open('ground_truth') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for filename, *numbers in reader:
        k1, k2 = re.findall(r'\d+', filename)  # no need to even convert to int
        key = '{}-{}'.format(k1, k2)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = (int(float(n)) for n in numbers)
        new_data.setdefault(key, []).append([x1, y1, x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2])
```